# Spaces returning all results in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a pretty big problem. I am allowing users to search for other users by interest. The problem is, if a user types in any more than one space, it returns every user (it even duplicates some). What can i do to stop this?

Here is my code, well all that you need to see what is going on:

```
    $connect= mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'shar31t');

    if (isset($_GET['interest']) && $_GET['interest'] != " ") {
        $interest= rtrim($_GET['interest']);
        $interest= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $interest);
        $query= "SELECT user_id FROM interests WHERE interest LIKE 
            '%".$interest."%'";
        $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            }
```

Thanks

Matt

Comment: use [trim](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function

Comment: why do you have a conditional like `$_GET['interest'] != " "`? I don't understand the space there.  Does entering a single space in `interest` supposed to convey some special meaning?  May check `!is_empty($_GET['interest'])`

Comment: Well it was initially to prevent ONE space from entering the query. But it only does one. Also, spaces for some reason make it through the !empty() condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with Nelson's answer, do a `SELECT distinct user_id` to avoid duplicates, as it seems a user can have multiple interests.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your following line:

```
if (isset($_GET['interest']) && $_GET['interest'] != " ") {
```

for this one:

```
if (isset($_GET['interest']) && trim($_GET['interest']) != '') {
```

that should prevent an empty string to get to your query.

Comment: And "SELECT DISTINCT" to avoid duplicating users that have multiple interests.

Comment: Why not use the `empty()` function instead of the statement `$_GET['interest'] != ''`